# Giving certain cells different background colors and borders?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How would I go about giving certain cells different background colors and borders?

I tried searching it up, but the only solution pertaied to giving random cells certain colors.

Comment: what type of pattern are you looking for to set the background color? please try to illustrate your question!

Comment: Lets say i have a list of data, for example contacts, one contact is my best friend. Each contact goes in a cell, and i want the cell belonging to the best friend contact to be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you determine which cells should receive it.

For example if you want every other cell to have a red background with a white border, you could do this in the cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
// This changes the cell to w/e you want it to look like
if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
    cell.backgroundcolor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor()
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
}
//Because I don't reset the state of the cell in this branch of the if statement, 
//before I update it, this cell could have the white border color, or it could have 
//the green border that is the default. This is all due to the view reusing cells.
// also don't forget to reset the corner radius / masks to bounds, forgetting to do 
//this, will lead to some cells having a corner radius and some not.
else if indexPath.row % 3 == 0 {
    cell.backGroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
//this resets the cell to its original state
else {
    cell.backGroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor.CGColor()
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
}
```

But in reality the check in the if statement could be anything, just make sure when you're reusing cells that you reset the state of the cell to its original state, before you go and modify it again.

Comment: This code won't work because as the table is scrolled you will end up with lots of rows having the wrong color.

Comment: Yes it is. Cells get reused. A cell may first get used as an even row so your code makes it red. As the table is scrolled, the cell may get reused for an odd row but your code doesn't reset the color so it incorrectly stays red. You need an `else` to your `if` that resets the color and border.

Comment: @rmaddy that's why i wrote, beneath the lines of code, that you have to reset the state of the cell to its original state. please read the entire post before.

Comment: OK, I missed the very last sentence of your answer. But as written, it is misleading because the code, as written, will cause problems. Your answer would be better if the code you posted had an `else` with at least a comment stating to "reset everything here". Given the nature of the question the OP will have no idea that code will be needed to deal with this and will end up posting another question asking why the cell colors are all message as the table scrolls.

Comment: What if I have  a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h and i determine c has a red background!

Comment: @0295694 i have no idea what you mean by that, can you please elaborate.

Comment: @Jay Based on your update, your `else if indexPath.row %3 == 0` block needs to do something with the `layer`. Otherwise it will be wrong depending on how the cell gets reused.

Comment: Sorry, lets say i have a list of data, for example contacts, one concact is my best friend. Each conctact goes in a cell, and i want the cell bellonging  to the best friend contact to be red.

Comment: @rmaddy how? if i don't do anything with the layer, it will remain however it was edited by the other two branches.

Comment: @0295694 one way you could do that is when you're storing that user information, or editing that user information in a view separate from the UICollectionView, however the user data is stored, just add a variable that can notify the if statement that it is in fact a special case.

Comment: @0295694 so if you have an array of contact objects, if each object had a variable named "isBestFriend", if you were to set that to true, then the if statement could be: if contact.isBestFriend { //do what you want here }

Comment: @Jay What do you want the border to be when the background is blue? Do you want the green border or the white border or a specific border? As written, some cells with a blue background will have no border, some will have a green border, and some will have a white border.

Comment: @rmaddy that's the point I was trying to make, by not resetting the cell to its original state, the representation is ambiguous and not predictable.

Comment: @Jay And since that can't be the desired behavior, your answer should demonstrate the proper way to write the code. As written, your code is just going to confuse anyone looking at it. Remember, 95% (made up number) of the people that make use of your answer in the future are simply going to copy and paste the code as-is (and maybe change the colors). When it doesn't work as-is, they will complain and down vote your answer for not working.

Comment: @O295694 could you make the answer as correct if it helped please?

Comment: @rmaddy I haven't gotten the chance to try it, it seems right. What potential issues may arise ftom using it.

Comment: @O295694 I edited the problem he was describing, the fact that I didn't "reset" the corner radius, could cause confusion to people copying / pasta the code. because some cells would have a cornerRadius of 5 while some would have 0. For what would appear to be no reason.

Answer (score 0):

set the cell's `backgroundColor` and `layer.borderColor` / `layer.borderWidth` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` depending on the `indexPath` property...